# Compile map reduce java file (containing main) with a class definition in a different java file

Tags: java, compilation, mapreduce

I am trying to compile kmeans.java which uses a FloatArrayWritable class . I have defined this class in FloatArrayWritable.java:

```
public class FoatArrayWritable implements Writable {

    public ArrayWritable array;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public FloatArrayWritable() {
        this(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
    }

    public FloatArrayWritable(FloatWritable[] vectors) {
        array = new ArrayWritable(Float.class, vectors);
    }

    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        array.readFields(in);
    }

public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        array.write(out);
    }

}
```

when I compile with this command:
javac -classpath /home/aniruddha/team05/NGramCount/lib/hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar -d kmeans_classes/ -Xlint kmeans.java FloatArrayWritable.java

I experience this error:
FloatArrayWritable.java:22: invalid method declaration; return type required
        public FloatArrayWritable() {
               ^
FloatArrayWritable.java:26: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public FloatArrayWritable(FloatWritable[] vectors) {
           ^
2 errors

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like your fingers betrayed you:

> public class **Foat** ArrayWritable implements Writable {

Comment: That explains the compiler error because a constructor matches a normal method signature except of course the lack of a return type. If the constructor name doesn't match the class name, it assumes a method and expects a return type.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure the class name matches the constructor name.

The compiler error occurs because a constructor matches a normal method signature except of course the lack of a return type. If the constructor name doesn't match the class name, it assumes a method and expects a return type.